# Eigenvalues of scaling of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a (real or complex) square matrix, let $\alpha \neq 0$.

> Is it true that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if and only if $\alpha \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\alpha A$?

I think yes, here is why I suppose so: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A \iff\lambda I- A$ is non injective $\iff \alpha \lambda I - \alpha A$ is non injective $\iff \alpha \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\alpha A$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It's essentially correct, yea.

Comment: Yeah. If explaining to an audience, you might note where you're using $\alpha$ nonzero (in the $\impliedby$ direction of the second $\iff$). I could potentially understand somebody wanting to see more detail on the $\implies$ direction there too. The outer $\iff$s are definitions (or equivalent to definitions) which probably need no explanation

Comment: As leslie said, I think it would be clearer if you use eigenvectors of $A$ and identify new eigenvectors from these for $\alpha A$ (and explain that the vectors remain nonzero as $\alpha\neq0$).

Comment: assume $A$ is upper triangular and check the diagonals.  If working over reals you can make this block upper triangular if needed.